# Implicit hidden assumptions of Mathematica with Limit

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I've stumbled upon the following symbolic limit (a tricky one):

```
Limit[(Sqrt[2]  v)/Sqrt[v^2 - c^2 (1 - 1/c Sqrt[c^2 - v^2])], v -> 0]
```

Mathematica gives 0 as result.

Yet the expected result was `2` and that result can be actually be reproduced in Mathematica with the code

```
Limit[(Sqrt[2]  v)/Sqrt[v^2 - c^2 (1 - 1/c Sqrt[c^2 - v^2])], v -> 0,  Assumptions -> c > 0]
```

So I understand that by default, without an explicit `Assumption` statement, Mathematica assumes (by default) `c<0` and gives no warnings/information about that implicit assumption.

Since I've lost some time to check with Mathematica my expected result (not imagining that Mathematica would assume `c<0`) I'd like to understand better the rationale behind Mathematica implicit hidden assumptions with symbolic calculations.

Btw the following limit (equivalent to the one given above for `c>0`) gives directly the expected result without having to insert the assumption `c>0`

```
Limit[(Sqrt[2]  v)/Sqrt[v^2 - c^2 (1 - Sqrt[(c^2 - v^2)/c^2])], v -> 0]
```

Any help to get a better understanding about this case?

[My Mathematica version is 10.1.0.0]

Comment: It is likely that Mathematica is assuming c is complex-valued (rather than negative real) when no other explicit assumptions are made.

Comment: Ok. Yet the assumption c \[Element] Reals doesn't change the result 0

Comment: Same with `Series[(Sqrt[2] v)/Sqrt[v^2 - c^2 (1 - 1/c Sqrt[c^2 - v^2])], {v, 0, 
  1}]`.

Comment: The fact that the limit with a certain assumption yields the same result as the limit without assumptions does not imply that Mathematica makes the same assumption. That's a logical fallacy.

Comment: What @SjoerdC.deVries stated is in fact the case here; `Limit` uses `Series`, and `Series` without any assumption happens to be the same as `Series` with the assumption `c<0`. So `Limit` gives the same result with no assumption as it does with the unwanted assumption.

Comment: Aside from the assumption on `c > 0` you're forgetting to specify the limit direction. The limits from below and above are different, so actually the limit as `v → 0` does not exist with `c > 0`. Maybe Mathematica drops the values of `c` where the limit is undefined and in those where it exists it computes it as zero. This command works (with the original form of your function): `Limit[(Sqrt[2] v)/Sqrt[v^2 - c^2 (1 - 1/c Sqrt[c^2 - v^2])], v -> 0, 
 Direction -> -1, Assumptions -> {c > 0}]`